# Second Nuget's Build target not executing

Tags: nuget, blazor-webassembly, target

I created two nuget packages for my two webassembly projects Client1 and Client2 and added a build target for each to retrieve the css files from that client and copy them to the main project, While everything in two clients are identical but the build target fromm Client1 executes and places css files in wwwroot\client1 of the main project, but wwwroot\client2 is not created when built, these are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I set both target files and css files to copyalways and they are in their bin folders but the second client files are not copied to the main project. why and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Client2 Blazor project you didn't have Client2 Folder under wwwroot path image is showing Client1. @mz1378

Comment: This is the main project and client2 should be created here. But it doesn't. This is the main problem of this question.

Comment: then where is Client2 Folder

Comment: The problem can my be webapplication or classlibrary which is copying you can remove this from web.config and can directly add in your project post build event these line